# AddRedirectToWww() does not redirect to the www domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've set up an asp.net Core 2 web application to run on an Azure App Service with a custom domain. I'd like to achieve redirecting the *example.com* calls to *https://www.example.com/*

So I've put a rewriter to my app's Startup.cs like this:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirectToWww()
                .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()                
                );
```

Unfortunately only the https redirection seems to be working. I've also tried  with `.AddRedirectToWwwPremanent()` as well, but when I trace the network traffic, there is only one 301 status code for https and the published app is not redirecting the non-www calls.

Comment: Share us your `Startup.cs` content, I fail to reproduce your issue with these code.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://github.com/messerke/devs/blob/master/Startup.cs

Comment: I'm having the same issue in .NET 6. Did you ever solve this @messerke?

Comment: @JohannesMols, no, using .net I was not successful solving this. As a workaround, I have solved this by adding the non-www version of my domain using my registrar